# Scraping parameterized url with scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I have a spider running using python scrapy, which is scraping all pages apart from pages with parameters(i.e. `&` symbols), such as, `http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B003ZDXHSG/ref=s9_simh_gw_p23_d0_i3?pf_rd_m=A3P5ROKL5A1OLE&pf_rd_s=center-2&pf_rd_r=1NWN2VXCA63R7TDYC3KQ&pf_rd_t=101&pf_rd_p=467128533&pf_rd_i=468294`.

The error log says `[scrapy] ERROR: xxx matching query does not exist.`

I am using the `CrawlSpider` with the following `SgmlLinkExtractor rule`

```
rules = (
       Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow='[a-zA-Z0-9.:\/=_?&-]+$'),
            'parse',
            follow=True,
        ),
)
```

Will really appreciate for your time and would like to have the privilege to thank you in advance.

Comment: the callback for CrawlSpider must not be named 'parse' see  http://readthedocs.org/docs/scrapy/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawling-rules

Answer (score 1):

To respond to my own answer, all my code were fine. The reason it was failing is the way I was calling the scrapy. It breaks in `&` as I was using single quote.
Using the double quote to call the spider is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your expression matches the url as far as `re.serach()` is concerned. Have you tried using `r'regexpression'` so python treats the string as a raw string? It appears to match both using a raw and a processed string but it is always best to have python treat regex as raw strings.

```
>>> import re
>>> url="http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B003ZDXHSG/ref=s9_simh_gw_p23_d0_i3?pf_rd_m=A3P5ROKL5A1OLE&pf_rd_s=center-2&pf_rd_r=1NWN2VXCA63R7TDYC3KQ&pf_rd_t=101&pf_rd_p=467128533&pf_rd_i=468294" 
>>> m = re.search(r'[a-zA-Z0-9.:\/=_?&-]+$', url) 
>>> m.group()
'http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B003ZDXHSG/ref=s9_simh_gw_p23_d0_i3?pf_rd_m=A3P5ROKL5A1OLE&pf_rd_s=center-2&pf_rd_r=1NWN2VXCA63R7TDYC3KQ&pf_rd_t=101&pf_rd_p=467128533&pf_rd_i=468294'

>>> m = re.search('[a-zA-Z0-9.:\/=_?&-]+$', url)
>>> m.group()
'http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B003ZDXHSG/ref=s9_simh_gw_p23_d0_i3?pf_rd_m=A3P5ROKL5A1OLE&pf_rd_s=center-2&pf_rd_r=1NWN2VXCA63R7TDYC3KQ&pf_rd_t=101&pf_rd_p=467128533&pf_rd_i=468294'
```